# Python's hashlib produces inconsistent results

Tags: python, hash, md5

So I'm trying to write a program that can create an account, by creating a .txt file that's the usernames, and then hashes the password with md5 and puts it in the file. However, whenever I run

> hashlib.md5(pasw.encode)

it produces bizarrely inconsistent results, that vary whether it encodes it in a function or not, and last time I tested it seemed to produce a random hash the first time ran. Now, when testing in a new project it sometimes produces the same hash for different strings. I've tried everything I could think of and I've got nothing. You can see some of the things I've tried to do.
Thanks in advance for the help, sorry if my code looks horrible I'm doing this project to learn. Here's the full code, sorry if some is irrelevant:

```
import hashlib

# Creates an account
def create():
    print('Create an account')
    user = input('Please enter a username: ')
    pasw = input('Please enter a password: ')
    usef = user+'.txt'
    f = open(usef,'w')
    # hash'd it
    hash_object = str(hashlib.md5(pasw.encode()))
    # Printing hash for debug
    print(hash_object)
    # This doesn't help but I tried
    hash_object = str(hashlib.md5(pasw.encode()))
    # Printing hash for debug
    print(hash_object)
    f.write(hash_object)
    f.close()

# Logs into a pre-existing account
def login():
    print('Welcome! To log in:')
    user = input('Please enter a username: ')
    pasw = input('Please enter a password: ')
    usef = user+'.txt'
    # Comparative hash
    hash_object = str(hashlib.md5(pasw.encode()))
    # Printing hash for debug
    print(hash_object)
    # This doesn't help but I tried
    hash_object = str(hashlib.md5(pasw.encode()))
    # Printing hash for debug
    print(hash_object)
    f = open(usef,'r')
    # Checks to see if it's right
    if hash_object == f:
        print('Welcome, '+user+'!')
        return(user)
    else:
        print('User/password not found')
        return(0)

# Changes a password for a user
def change(user):
    while True:
        pasw = input('Please enter your current password: ')
        usef = user+'.txt'
        hash_object = str(hashlib.md5(pasw.encode()))
        # Printing hash for debug
        print(hash_object)
        # This doesn't help but I tried
        hash_object = str(hashlib.md5(pasw.encode()))
        f = open(usef,'r')
        if hash_object == f:
            pasw = input('Please enter your new password: ')
            past = input('Please repeat your new password: ')
            while True:
                if pasw == past:
                    usef = p+'.txt'
                    f = open(usef,'w')
                    hash_object = str(hashlib.md5(pasw.encode()))
                    # Printing hash for debug
                    print(hash_object)
                    # This doesn't help but I tried
                    hash_object = str(hashlib.md5(pasw.encode()))
                    f.write(hash_object)
                    f.close()
                    print('Done!')
                    return()
                else:
                    print('They aren\'t the same')
                    pass
        else:
            print('That doesn\'t match the password on the system')

# Help with commands
def halp():
    print('You can type "Create" to create an account')
    print('You can type "Login" to log into a pre-existing account')
    print('More functionality will be added')
    print('Maybe')

# =============== Main Body of Code ==================

while True:
    print('What do you want to do?')
    print('Type "Help" for commands')
    x = input()
    x = x.upper()
    if x == 'CREATE':
        create()
    elif x == 'LOGIN':
        p = login()
        if p != 0:
            while True:
                print('What would you like to do now?')
                print('"Logout" to log out')
                print('or "Change password"')
                print('I think you can guess that')
                x = input()
                x = x.upper()
                if x == 'CHANGE PASSWORD':
                    change(p)
    elif x == 'HELP':
        halp()
    elif x == 'DEV':
        y = input()
        print(str(hashlib.md5(y.encode())))
        # This doesn't help but I tried
        print(str(hashlib.md5(y.encode())))
    else:
        print("Command not found")
        print("There are four commands")
        print("It's not that hard")
```

edit: Oh, I understand now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `hashlib.md5(y.encode())` will return a hash-object, you have to call its `digest` or `hexdigest` method to get the actual hash value

Comment: look at the first example here https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html